# BeautifulSoup extract the value without class in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract data using BeautifulSoup in Python.

My document :

```
<div class="listing-item" data-id="309531" data-score="0">

  <div class="thumb">
    <a href="https://res.cloudinary.com/">

      <div style="background-image:url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dubizzle-com/image/upload/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_5:2292,y_50/co_rgb:FFFFFF,l_text:oswald_100_bold_letter_spacing_5:01,y_-107/c_fit,w_200/abu-dhabi-plate_private-car_classic);"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I want to get the background image URL from

```
<div style="background-image:url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dubizzle-com/image/upload/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_5:2292,y_50/co_rgb:FFFFFF,l_text:oswald_100_bold_letter_spacing_5:01,y_-107/c_fit,w_200/abu-dhabi-plate_private-car_classic);"></div>
```

My Code :

```
from textwrap import shorten
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl, urljoin, urlparse
import requests

url = 'https://uae.dubizzle.com/motors/number-plates/?page={}'

print('{:^50} {:^15} {:^25} '.format('Title', 'Pice', 'Date'))

for page in range(0, 40):   # <--- Increase to number pages you want
    response = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    for title, price, date, thumb  in zip(soup.select('.listing-item .title'),
                            soup.select('.listing-item .price'),
                            soup.select('.listing-item .date'),
                            soup.select('.listing-item .thumb')):

        print('{:50} {:<25} {:<15}'.format(shorten(title.get_text().strip(), 50), price.get_text().strip(), thumb.get_text().strip()))
```

how can I get the background image URL from the document?

Answer (score 1):

You have access to the url by searching inside your `thumb` value.

You can try this:

**CODE:**

```
from textwrap import shorten
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl, urljoin, urlparse
import requests

url = 'https://uae.dubizzle.com/motors/number-plates/?page={}'

print('{:^50} {:^15} {:^25} '.format('Title', 'Price', 'Date'))

for page in range(0, 1):   # <--- Increase to number pages you want
    response = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    for title, price, date, thumb  in zip(soup.select('.listing-item .title'),soup.select('.listing-item .price'),soup.select('.listing-item .date'),soup.select('.listing-item .thumb')):
        # url = thumb.find('div').get('style').split('url(')[1].split(');')[0])
        print('{:50} {:<25} {:<15}'.format(shorten(title.get_text().strip(),50),price.get_text().strip(), thumb.find('div').get('style').split('url(')[1].split(');')[0]))
```

Comment: you can use `thumb.find('a')['href']` instead of `thumb.find('div').get('style').split('url(')[1].split(');')[0]`

Comment: @Shijith I think he wants the image link. In this case the `href` links to another page, the image is stored in the background-image

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the find_next('div') to get the div element and then get the style attribute.Use regular expression to get the Image Url.

Try Below code.

```
from textwrap import shorten
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://uae.dubizzle.com/motors/number-plates/?page={}'

print('{:^50} {:^15} {:^25} '.format('Title', 'Pice', 'Date'))

for page in range(0, 40):   # <--- Increase to number pages you want
    response = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    for title, price, date, thumb  in zip(soup.select('.listing-item .title'),
                            soup.select('.listing-item .price'),
                            soup.select('.listing-item .date'),
                            soup.select('.listing-item .thumb')):


        print('{:50} {:<25} {:<15}'.format(shorten(title.get_text().strip(), 50), price.get_text().strip(), re.search("https?:\/\/[^\s]+[^);]", thumb.find_next("div")['style']).group(0)))
```

Here is some output on console:

```
G91911 - Excellent for PORSCHE                     AED 59,000                https://res.cloudinary.com/dubizzle-com/image/upload/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_5:88887,x_100,y_-50/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_5:J,x_-240,y_-50/c_fit,w_200/dubai-plate_private-car_new
R 199                                              AED 49,000                https://res.cloudinary.com/dubizzle-com/image/upload/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_5:2122,x_100,y_-50/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_5:M,x_-240,y_-50/c_fit,w_200/dubai-plate_private-car_new
88887 J                                            AED 49,000                https://res.cloudinary.com/dubizzle-com/image/upload/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_5:2212,x_100,y_-50/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_5:S,x_-240,y_-50/c_fit,w_200/dubai-plate_private-car_new
M2122                                              AED 52,000                https://res.cloudinary.com/dubizzle-com/image/upload/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_5:22022,x_100,y_-50/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_5:J,x_-240,y_-50/c_fit,w_200/dubai-plate_private-car_new
S 2212                                             AED 309,000               https://res.cloudinary.com/dubizzle-com/image/upload/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_5:5000,x_100,y_-50/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_5:L,x_-240,y_-50/c_fit,w_200/dubai-plate_private-car_new
22022 J                                            AED 9,500                 https://res.cloudinary.com/dubizzle-com/image/upload/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_4:5945,x_100,y_-50/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_4:H,x_-240,y_-50/c_fit,w_200/dubai-plate_private-car_classic
5000 L                                             AED 2,800,000             https://res.cloudinary.com/dubizzle-com/image/upload/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_4:90,x_100,y_-50/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_4:Z,x_-240,y_-50/c_fit,w_200/dubai-plate_private-car_classic
Dubai                                              AED 760,000               https://res.cloudinary.com/dubizzle-com/image/upload/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_4:10000,x_100,y_-50/co_rgb:242424,l_text:oswald_140_bold_letter_spacing_4:H,x_-240,y_-50/c_fit,w_200/dubai-plate_private-car_classic
```